# Django M2M Form

Tags: django, forms, m2m

i try to do checkboxes in form for M2M field, but have this error, have no idea how to fix it. Google didn't help me, i tried.

When i render objects as list, i can select few objects and save it, so problem is not in views.py ,but it doesn't work with checkboxes.

My code:

forms.py

```
class CheckoutForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Checkout
        fields = ('dishes', 'user')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(CheckoutForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields["dishes"].widget = CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields["dishes"].queryset = Dish.objects.all()
```

so only way that i can see an form error:

render form fields - send a empty form - put back {{ form.as_p }} - i can see an error "field is required"

page.html

```
<form class="p-2" action="{% url 'make_order' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <select name="user">
            <option value="{{ user.id }}">{{ user }}</option>
        </select>
                <div
          class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-5 g-2"
          style="margin-left: -40px"
        >
          {% for dish in dishes %}
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card" style="width: 14rem">
              <img
                class="card-img-top"
                style="width: 220px; height: 240px"
                src="{{ dish.image.url }}"
                alt="Card image cap"
              />
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ dish.name }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Description: {{ dish.description }}</p>
                <p class="card-text">Ingredients: {{ dish.ingredients }} g</p>
                <p class="card-text">Serving size: {{ dish.serving_size }} g</p>
                <p class="card-text">Price: {{ dish.price }} UAH</p>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  class="btn btn-primary"
                  name="dishes"
                  id="{{ dish.id }}"
                  value="{{ dish.id }}"
                />Add to cart
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
          <input type="submit" value="ADD" class="btn btn-primary" />

      </form>
```

views.py

```
class OrderView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Checkout
    template_name = "food_order/make_order.html"
    form_class = CheckoutForm
    success_url = "/order/"

    login_url = "/login/"
    raise_exception = True

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print('i am here')
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = self.request.user
        instance.save()
        dishes = form.cleaned_data["dishes"]
        for dish in dishes:
            dish, created = Dish.objects.get_or_create(name = dish)
            dish.save()
            instance.dishes.add(dish)
            instance.save()
            print(instance.dishes)
        print(instance)
        form.save_m2m()
        return super(OrderView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(OrderView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["dishes"] = Dish.objects.all()
        context["orders"] = Checkout.objects.all()
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to be tinkering with `__init__` here when setting the widget. It may be overwriting your values for a modelform.

Try:

```
class CheckoutForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Checkout
        fields = ('dishes', 'user',)
        widgets = {'dishes': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple() }
```

This should work as m2m fields have the ModelMultipleChoiceField by default. If you want to make it all explicit, you can go with:

```
class CheckoutForm(forms.ModelForm):

    dishes = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Dish.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Checkout
        fields = ('dishes', 'user',)
```

**If you are formatting the checkboxes by hand**

make sure they have `name="dishes"`  (assuming `dishes` is the name of the field in your Checkout model) and `value="<the dish id>"`

You may also need to grab the values submitted with request.POST.getList('dishes'), otherwise you will ony get one value submitted

Comment: nope, same problem

i think django doesn't understand which checkboxes are selected.
so POST send "on" checkboxes but django can't convert "on" checkboxes to exactly value.

Comment: A checked checkbox will POST its `value="myvalue"`, the value will only be `on` if there's no `value=`  attribute, and it won't send anything if unchecked.  In this case the value should be the id of the dish. If you are letting Django handle the HTML of the form, can you confirm that the individual dishes checkboxes have `value` attributes?

Comment: thanks, i don't know how i skipped value attribute, so it works now

Comment: nope, still doesn't work
now error "this field is required" however i choose a dishes

Comment: Sounds like you might have missed the name attribute, which should be 'dishes', the same as the m2m field. How are you generating the form in the template? Django should be able to handle this for you as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Comment: i have "name="dishes"" attribute

Comment: Can you provide the HTML for the form?  It sounds like something is slightly broken so that the field isn't being properly recognised.

Comment: so, i updated question, there u can find my html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251096/discussion-between-samsparx-and-oleksandr-dimbrovskyi).